# MS SQL Server Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint when parsing dates

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to run a query on a SQL Server. The query gets some string values from a php script and I am converting them to datetime to get the results back. I have searched for hours and still can't figure out how to parse these values correctly.

My query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalVisits 
FROM dm_visita v 
INNER JOIN dm_medicos m ON m.Id_Medico = v.Id_Medico 
WHERE v.Fec_Registro 
BETWEEN convert(datetime,'2016-05-30 00:00:00.000',121) AND convert(datetime,'2016-06-26 23:59:59.000',121)
```

And the error I keep getting is:

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint
```

How can I parse these values correctly to run my query?

Comment: What are the data types for the columns Id_Medico (in both tables) and Fec_Registro? My first guess would be that one of the tables has Id_Medico as NVARCHAR and the other has it as BIGINT and there's at least one case where the NVARCHAR Id_Medico can't be converted (e.g. it's null or has something other than a number in it). If that's the case, try a `CAST` to NVARCHAR on the one that's a bigint in the join.

Comment: You were right!! I casted to NVARCHAR since one table had Id_Medico as BIGINT and the other had it as NVARCHAR. Now the query runs smoothly!! How can I vote your answer?

Comment: @jabobadilla, you might click on *ZLK* and vote on any other answer. Points don't smell :-)